# MySQL query - retrieve rows that only contain letters and spaces

Tags: php, mysql

I want to construct a query that returns a list of locations from a GeoCache table so I can calculate the top searched for locations.  The geocache table gets filled with location searches from users.

I want to discount postcodes and long form addresses so really I only want searches that are letters and spaces i.e. "Manchester" as opposed to "1 This Street, Place, Manchester"

I have a list of towns in a seperate table that I could match against, but the two are not linked directly.

How best can I retrieve a list of top locations (my table has a `geocache_count` column) that match my requirements?

My table essentially looks like this:

```
geocache_id
geocache_place /* this is where the search ends up */
geocache_lat
geocache_lng
geocache_count
```

Comment: You want to find rows that contain address like `1 This Street, Place, Manchester` ?

Comment: No, I want to find rows that arent like that, i.e. no numbers, no commas. I want to find rows that contain letters and spaces only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression for this, But this will be little slower.

```
WHERE `geocache_place` RLIKE '^[[:alnum:]]+$';
```

Top location can be found by adding a `ORDER BY` clause on the expression how you want to determine the top.

Comment: This is great, how do I get it for numbers only?

Comment: @Chris For numbers its `^[[:digit:]]+$`. Read more about [regular expression on MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Sorry I meant letters only, but I found it thanks : `'^[a-z ]+$'`

Comment: @Chris `[a-z ]` matches latin a-z and space character. It'll not match any other language characters. Its better to use `[[:alpha:][:space:]]` which is same as `[a-z ]` but matches any character from any language.